# adding new line to db , but without /n

Tags: php, database, html-entities

Simple example

```
$text = 'First line
second line';
```

I want the text to have a new line but in the db , no to be stored `/n`

I try with

`htmlentities()`,`htmlspecialchars()` and I also try this

```
$text = str_replace("\n", "&#60;&#98;&#114;&#47;&#62",$text);
```

Comment: $text = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $text); ??

Comment: Why do you not want it to be a `newline`?

Comment: use `$text = nl2br($text);`. if you are using it to show as html, it would be advisable to store it as it is and in display show it as `<br />`.

Comment: I dont want new line to the db , because I user serialize() and that new line make some stuff not to work

Comment: Now in the db , there is <br />. But that also is showing with the text , it dosent make a new line.

Comment: is the text html, or being used on a web page?

Comment: yes, is being used on a web page

Comment: then <br> is a valid break, i would guess you are encoding the < and >

Comment: yes i'm using htmlspecialchars, addslashed and trim before inserting

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode make the new line, but is this the best way ?

Comment: well then what did you expect